# File transfer using strophe library

Tags: xmpp, strophe

How the files can be transferred between users in a chat using strophe library in XMPP

Comment: Dupplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304078/xmpp-file-transfer-using-strophe-library

Comment: possible duplicate of [File transfer using jingle in XMPP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965303/file-transfer-using-jingle-in-xmpp)